# Taylor Series of a logarithmic function

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, differentiation, approximations, calculus

I was reading *Intro to Modern Statistical Mechanics* by David Chandler, on page 63. He states the following:

> we can expand $\ln\Omega(E-E_v)$ in the Taylor series $$\ln\Omega(E-E_v) = \ln\Omega(E) - E_v\frac{d\ln\Omega}{dE} +  \cdots $$
>
> Here $E_v$ denotes the energy for a particular system state $v$.

I was trying to compare this to the Taylor series formula:
$$ f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \frac{f''(a)(x-a)^2}{2!}+ \cdots$$

But I am not sure I am following what the author said.

Comment: Note that the Taylor serie for logarithm has very slow convergence. With advantage is used e.g the Padé approximation instead. See www.nezumi.demon.co.uk/consult/logx.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that $\Omega$ is a function of $E$ so you have to use the chain rule. The equivalent mathematical formulation is -
$$\ln(f(a-x))\approx\ln(f(a))-\underbrace{\frac{f'(a)}{f(a)}}_{\frac{\partial\ln(f(x))}{\partial x}\large|_{x=a}}x+\dots$$

and so on... Use the following command in mathematica/WolfraAlpha to get expansion to order $n$ (replace $n$ with integer)

```
Series[Log[f[a - x]], {x, 0, n}]
```

Comment: Good answer, although the Mathematica command seems like an unnecessary addition.